# how to provide specific font-size for each breakpoints in mui createTheme on react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes, breakpoints, font-size

I'm currently trying to create a mui theme for our react project and I wondered if it is possible to specify a font-size for each breakpoints. 
Something like :

```
h3: {
      fontSize: {
      xs: "1.5rem",
      xl: "2rem",
      ...
     }
      fontWeight: "bold",
      lineHeight: "2.25rem",
    },
```

I know this code is not valid but it is so you get the idea of what i'm looking for. 
Same thing for line-height. 
It is the first time i'm creating a custom theme so i'm not very familiar with all that.